# I have created modules for different components but loadChildren is nor=t working for modules

Tags: angular

I am using the below code to use loadChildren for login-module, but it is showing error "ERROR Error:

> "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module
>   './login/login.module'"

```
 {
      path: 'login',
      loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' 

     },
```

And component module for login is:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LoginRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

login-routing.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {}
```

-

Comment: can please show us project structure?

Answer (score 1):

The path to your module should be absolute from src.

```
  loadChildren: 'src/app/login/login.module#LoginModule'
```

Comment: hi, that particular error is removed by using this path, but i got another error "ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type LoginComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and LoginModule! Please consider moving LoginComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and LoginModule."

Comment: @shivtajvirk the issue is self explanatory and not related to the original question. Consider upvoting and accpeting the answer that helped you for the issue you had, and if you have a new one that you can't seem to resolve, please create a new question on SOF.